# what is the correct syntax form for this to function -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-sql

In the following lines of code, I try to add a function inside html tag in javascript:

```
nuevo = "<p class='item'>" + res.tarea + "<button onclick = '" + return EliminarTareas(database) + (" + res.tarea +");'>" + "Eliminar" + "</button></p>";
$('#listatareas').append(nuevo);
function EliminarTareas(id, base) {
     base.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DELETE tarea FROM Tareas WHERE tarea=?", [id], function () {
        });
     });
 }
```

Comment: Just a quick glance it looks like your ' ' and " " are mixed up double check all of those.

Comment: @jdphenix I think client side sql is kind of the option when you're dealing with client-side browser databases.

Comment: res = results.rows.item(i);

 var sql = 'INSERT INTO Tareas(tarea, mes, dia, fecha)\n\
                               VALUES(?,?,?,?)';

var tarea = {
                 fecha: fechahoy,
                 mes: m,
                 dia: d,
                 tarea: tareas 
             };   

tx.executeSql(sql, [tarea.tarea, tarea.mes, tarea.dia, tarea.fecha])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this part `+return EliminarTareas(" + database + ", " + res.tarea +");'>"`. It discards the second parameter since you closed the paranthesis `)`, and it also has quote problems.
It should be like this `+" return EliminarTareas(" + database + ", " + res.tarea + ");'>"`

However, I believe addressing this task with `.data` would be effective, and it may provide a better structure. Below is my version with some codes from yours (DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/9q4hLs3a/):

```
var nuevo = $("<p class='item'><button data-var1='" + database + "' data-var2='" + res.tarea + "'>Eliminar</button></p>");

$('#listatareas').append(nuevo);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#listatareas button', function(){

    var var1 = $(this).data('var1');
    var var2 = $(this).data('var2');
    EliminarTareas(var1 , var2 )
});



function EliminarTareas(id, base){

    base.transaction(function(tx){

        tx.executeSql("DELETE tarea FROM Tareas WHERE tarea=?", [id], function (){

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks , are you a Great Master

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales thank you, I am just a learner.. :) would you please mark the post as the correct answer?

Comment: excuse me now have this problem, i dont know for what

$('body').on('click', '#listatareas button', function(){
         
         var var1 = $(this).data('var1');
         var var2 = $(this).data('var2');
         EliminarTareas(var1 , var2, date);
         
     });

function EliminarTareas(database, tarea, fech)

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionRecordatorio.js:194 EliminarTareasRecordatorio.js:183 (anonymous function)jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery-2.1.1.min.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales `EliminarTareas(var1 , var2, date)` where does `date` come?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales can you try this: `$(document)` instead of `(body)`

Comment: same error 

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
EliminarTareas (anonymous function)jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery-2.1.1.min.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle

Comment: the problem is that `EliminarTareas` creates the button to click.  This event can be only called when this button clicked, however the button will not be created since `EliminarTareas` will never be called. It is like chicken-egg thing. You may need to have this `nuevo = $("<p class='item'>"+ res.tarea +"<button data-var1='" + database + "' data-var2='" + res.tarea + "'>Eliminar</button></p>");` created somewhere else already, so that you can use `$(document).on('click', '#listatareas button', function()`

Comment: if I use $('body').on('click', '#listatareas button', function() the function EliminarTareas(var1 , var2, date); work, I try displaying the contents of the variables, but when i use $(document).on('click', '#listatareas button', function() the function dont work

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales so, it is working now? can you share the updated code `pastebin`?

Comment: no, and honestly do not know why
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
EliminarTareasRecordatorio.js:183 (anonymous function)
n.event.dispatch
n.event.add.r.handle

dont work, but if i only show the variables show this
[object Database] tgrgrt 2015-04-16, using $(document).on, i think the error is in the database

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales it should be something in this `Recordatorio.js` file!

Comment: i do it this http://pastebin.com/Xg9dTcgv, pass one data-parameter the tarea, and send databse and date out the tag, dont show me error but dont do it any thing

Comment: I will look into this tomorrow since it is late night here :) as last suggestion can you put the first two lines inside `$(document).ready(function(){...`

Comment: dont undestand the last u say but i try the solutionated do not understand what you say , because I have all code within the $(document).ready(function(){... , if u can doing a example in pastebin and show me

Comment: can u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710918/dont-store-data-in-database-web-sql-javascript?noredirect=1#comment47557552_29710918

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted

```
"<p class='item'>"+ res.tarea +"<button onclick = 'EliminarTareas("+database+","+res.tarea +")'>Eliminar</button></p>";
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: EliminarTareas is not defined

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

<!DOCTYPE html>, this line show error